# Variable in Thor desc

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface, thor

With a cli project I would like to have a shared super class with thor tasks. When calling the sub-command help it should expose the shared command with a custom description.

I came up with the code below, but the variable @plural is not substituted in the description.

Is this possible with Thor and some meta programming?

```
module MyModule
  class ResourceSubcommand < Thor

    def initialize(*args)
      super
    end

    desc "list", "list all #{@plural}"
    def list
      list_object(@default_list_columns)
    end
  end
end

module MyModule
  class Account < MyModule::ResourceSubcommand

    def initialize(*args)
      super
      @plural = 'accounts'
    end

  end
end

module MyModule
  class Commands < Thor

    desc "account SUBCOMMAND ...ARGS", "manage Exact Online accounts"
    subcommand "account", Account

  end
end
```

running `$ thorcli account help` should output:

```
Commands:
  thorcli account help [COMMAND]     # Describe subcommands or one specific subcommand
  thorcli account list               # list all accounts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string passed to `desc` is evaluated in the context of the **class**, but the `initialize` method is evaluated in the context of **instances**, so the two `@plural` belong to two different objects.

Further more, `desc` is called immediately when defining the superclass `MyModule::ResourceSubcommand`, and there is no easy way to postpone its evaluation after the superclass gets inherited and the `@plural` in the subclass is set, your goal seems very hard to achieve.

P.S. I've tried overriding `MyModule::ResourceSubcommand::inherited`, and `MyModule::ResourceSubcommand.singleton_class::inherited`, and I failed. Maybe you could define `MyModule::ResourceSubcommand` as a module, override its `self.included`, and include it **after** setting `@plural` in the subclass.

### UPDATE

I finally succeed. Here is my solution:

```
module MyModule

  # Change from class to module
  module ResourceSubcommand

    # A hook called when this module is included by other modules
    def self.included(base)
      base.class_eval do
        desc "list", "list all #{@plural}"
        def list
          list_object(@default_list_columns)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

module MyModule

  # No inheritance
  class Account

    # Don't put this in any instance methods, including #initialize
    @plural = 'accounts'

    # Be sure to include after @plural is set
    include ResourceSubcommand
  end
end
```